# Access a struct in an array by its parameter name

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

Let’s say we have an array of structs

```
struct userConfig: {

 let sampleConfig: [SampleConfig]?

}
```

inside the SampleConfig array we have:

```
struct SampleConfig: {

valueOne: String?

valueTwo: String?

}
```

I want to get the value of the "valueOne"

So I would do this:

```
userConfig?.sampleConfig?.[0]
```

but I want to get if by its parameter name "valueOne" not by is array order. Since the value can change.

Something like this:

```
userConfig?.sampleConfig?.valueOne
```

is there a way to do it?

Comment: `userConfig.sampleConfig?[0].valueOne`? That'd be the correct call... Then, it's unclear what you want " name "valueOne" not by is array order" how do you know which one if it can have multiple values? What's your goal?

Comment: @Larme thanks for your response, I may have phrased it incorrectly.  Lets say I am connected to an api and I need to get the "valueOne" value for each of the "userConfig" structs.  Would that be the best way to go about it?

Comment: You mean `userConfig.sampleConfig?.compactMap { $0.valueOne }`?  A for loop should also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is not make the array `Optional`. If you have no `SampleConfig`s, represent that with an empty array. So change `UserConfig` thus:

```
struct UserConfig {

 let sampleConfig: [SampleConfig]

}
```

Now, if you want to get a list of all the `valueOne` values, the easiest way is with `map()`

```
let allValueOnes = userConfig.sampleConfig.map { $0.valueOne }
```

That will give you a list of all `valueOne`s and put `nil`s in for those `SampleConfig`s where `valueOne` is `nil`. Or you can use `compactMap` which will filter out the `nil` `valueOne`s.